# Copy resource files to executed assembly

Tags: c#, resources

May be it's silly, in this case please tell me better way to manage that.

I have a Console application (**ConsoleProject**). It references to my Class library (**Library1**) and **Library1** references to another my Class library (**Library2**)

> ConsoleProject => Library1=>Library2

**Library2** has some text resource files to parse.(*Build action = **Content***, **Copy to Output Directory** = **Always**)

---

Is it possible, these files to be coppied to the executed path of **ConsoleProject**?

for now I have to add another reference **ConsoleProject**=>**Library2** just for these files. I would like to avoid this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make those files as embedded resource.
2. Right click on those files and Set the CopyToOutputDirectory to Copy always

**UPDATE:**
Post Build Commands:

```
if not exist c:\somedir\bin md c:\somedir\bin
xcopy /y c:\yourcodedir\bin\abc.txt c:\somedir\bin
```

Comment: I think he doesn't want the first stpep.

Comment: yep, you are right, I just want to put these files near the executed one

Comment: Set the CopyToOutputDirectory to Copy always itself will serve the purpose, just mentioned the 2 appraochess

Comment: I initially set that to "Copy always" but unfortunatelly didn't help. May be embeding is the only workaround

Comment: You may need to do it in the Post Build event. Write post build build event scripts to do this. Updated the answer

Comment: Thanks for the given direction

Answer (score 1):

If possible I would make those files and embedded resource in your Library2.dll and then stream them to a temp location when needed for the use in your console program.  This is the cleanest way of doing it and is less prone to build / file copy issues later.

Here is a post I did surrounding managing file dependencies with unit / integration testing which provides some examples on how to manage the files appropriately.

http://tsells.wordpress.com/2012/03/06/how-to-run-integration-tests-with-file-dependencies/